# javascript copy (duplicate) text from 1 field to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 20 fields

10 with **name=** from 1 to 10 
and 10 fields with same name from 1 to 10

```
<input name="1"  type="text"> 
...
 <input name="10"  type="text">
```

and 10 fields like this

```
<input name="1"  type="text"> 
...
 <input name="10"  type="text">
```

so what i want is:  to write in first 10 fields , and other 10 to be filled automatically

i can change names to id or add prefix to id of second group. 
or its better with names .

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far, so we can help

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please include **surrounding html**, especially with **`id=`** or **`class=`** attributes that can help to distinguish the two groups.

Answer (score 0):

if u change names to  id 1-10  then second group id a1-a10

```
 function populateSecondTextBox() {
document.getElementById('1').value = document.getElementById('a1').value;
}
```

this is for 1 only,
someone can add answer for doing all with 1 code

Answer (score 0):

[image: Edit lpojo4172z]

you want to mirror the changes like this ?

```
for(let i=1; i<11 ; i++){

  let input = document.getElementsByName(i.toString())[0];
  let mirror = document.getElementsByName(i.toString())[1];

  input.onkeyup=()=>{ mirror.value = input.value; }

}
```

Comment: added a sandbox to see